# JavaScript arrow-function using navigator.userAgent as an example

Tags: javascript, user-agent, indexof, arrow-functions, navigator

```
const browser = ((agent) => {
    switch (true) {
        case agent.indexOf("edge") > -1: return "edge";
        case agent.indexOf("edg") > -1: return "chromium based edge (dev or canary)";
        case agent.indexOf("opr") > -1 && !!window.opr: return "opera";
        case agent.indexOf("chrome") > -1 && !!window.chrome: return "chrome";
        case agent.indexOf("trident") > -1: return "ie";
        case agent.indexOf("firefox") > -1: return "firefox";
        case agent.indexOf("safari") > -1: return "safari";
    default: return "other";
    }
}) (window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
```

There is a simple example how to detect browser using `navigator.userAgent` property of `Window` object. Could someone explain what the latest line of this code actually does and why `toLowerCase()` method is necessary here?

[*Source*](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/edde0150-9478-4ca6-ba0f-9e084b5a4719/how-to-detect-microsoft-edge-chromium-chrome-ie-browser-using-javascript?forum=iewebdevelopment)

Comment: Do some research on [what an IIFE is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) and how they work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> }
> ```

End of the arrow function

---

> ```
> )
> ```

End of the grouping operator that surrounds the arrow function

---

> ```
> (...)
> ```

Calls the function, with arguments

---

> ```
> window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()
> ```

The argument

---

> why toLowerCase() method is necessary here?

Because it is doing a case-insensitive comparison